# Disable authentication on some pages, only for local network requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis-express

I want to allow local network (intranet) users to access a specific page on my website without authentication.

I have found I could do this with location tag in config file ([here](https://forums.asp.net/post/2085285.aspx)), but this would also allow internet users to access the page without authentication.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you speak about location, i guess that you are using Asp.NET webforms

What about using the global.asax event AuthenticateRequest, 
and returning an error 403 when the user IP address is not from your intranet ?

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // if IP doesn't match, throw a 403 forbidden

}
```

You could also implement that in a HttpModule, but as AuthenticateRequest is a built-in app event, i'd just stick to it

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Authorization for users, and based on local IP address allow users to access that page otherwise redirect to login page or 401 page